# Create content in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7

Is it possible to have a create content link (node/add) specific to the node/page being viewed.
As an example, on a blog page user gets add/blog link on an article page - add/article.
And a similar question for taxonomy terms, on a page of term A any content that has been added automatically gets tagged with that term. On a page of term B - tagged with term B.
I don't want users manually select terms and content types each time they post.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject or alter node and comment links to link directly to the add page for the current content type via [hook_node_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) and [hook_comment_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_view_alter/7).

If you are viewing a term page (for term `foo`) which lists multiple content types including the article type and you want a link to the node-add page for the article type and automatically populate it with the term foo, then you will need a combination of `hook_node_view_alter` to inject a link to `node/add/article?term=3` (where 3 is the term ID of the current node / page) and `hook_form_alter` which alters the node form to read the tid from `term=3` and selects the related term.

Hope that made sense :)

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer but the problem is that i'm not a coder. So looking for existent ways - configuration of contribs (?)

Comment: Frankly, I don't believe that this can be accomplished without coding. IMHO, once you go beyond using Drupal for a "personal blog", you will need to learn how to tweak modules and themes using PHP.

The flip side is that once you get past some minor speedbumps, simple tweak is pretty easy in Drupal. You can see a related example of injecting links here: http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#node_links which should get your started. Good luck!